# in c declared matrix. and changing a matrix with word

Tags: c, matrix

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int a,d; 
char b;
float c;
char voca[100];
scanf("%d %c %f %d",&a,&b,&c,&d);
if (b = 'F')
    voca= "Food";
else if (b = 'S')
    voca= "Service";
else if (b = 'R')
    voca= "W/R Sales";
else
    voca= "Lodging";
printf("No Type      Ratio(\%) Enterprises\n%d  %s    %.1f\%      %7d", a, voca,c,d);
return 0;
}
```

I want to declare matrix first and i want to change it base on what is b is.
but i can't change it .

Comment: `if (b = 'F')` --> `if (b == 'F')`, same for `'S'` and `'R'`, also `voca= "Food";` should be `strcpy(voca, "Food");` or change `char voca[100]` to `char *voca;`, we can not assign to arrays using the `=` operator.

Comment: `=` is for value assignment. `==` is for value comparison.

Comment: Also, to print the `%` sign use `%%` instead of `\%`

Comment: You can't directly assign string literals to array of char in C. You should call strcpy, assign each of char in the array or change type of voca to const char*, if you're not willing to modify it after it's assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison operator is `==` not `=`

To change the contents of `voca`, you need to use `strcpy` or `memcpy`.

```
#include <string.h>
...
    if (b == 'F')
        strcpy(voca, "Food");
    else if (b == 'S')
        strcpy(voca,  "Service");
...
```